# Saving Oauth2RestTemplate/Client storing in Security Context

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am securing my web application with OAuth2. I have a custom Authentication Provider which stores the OAuth2Client(OAut2RestTemplate) in the Security Context.

CustomAuthenticationProvide

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();


        try {
            ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails passwordResourceDetails =
                    (ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails) new OAuth2Client(name, password).getResource();
            passwordResourceDetails.setUsername(name);
            passwordResourceDetails.setPassword(password);


            OAuth2Client client = new OAuth2Client(passwordResourceDetails);
            User user = client.getUser();
            if (!name.equals(user.getMail())) {
                throw new OAuth2AccessDeniedException();
            }
            return new AuthToken(name, password, new ArrayList<>(), user, client);
        } catch (OAuth2AccessDeniedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return aClass.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

AuthToken (Implementation of Authentication object)

```
public class AuthToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {
    private User user;
    private OAuth2Client client;

    AuthToken(Object principal, String credentials, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, User user, OAuth2Client client) {
        super(principal, credentials, authorities);
        this.user = user;
        this.client = client;
    }
    AuthToken(String principal, String credentials) {
        super(principal, credentials);
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public OAuth2Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }
}
```

First of all I want to know if this is secure ? Last time I was logging in. And after a while I saw the orders of the user who logged in after me. My next questin is, if there is a better/more beautiful solution. I was working with the Spring Security OAuth2 Documentation, but I didn't get it work. I had the same Client for all the user.

Example Controller Mapping

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/orders")
    public ModelAndView orders(AuthToken token, HttpServletRequest request) {
      if (token != null) {
            request.getSession().setAttribute("userAcc", token.getUser());
        }
        user = token.getUser();

        List<Statistics> statistics = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            List<Order> orders = Arrays.asList(token.getClient().getOrders());
            // @TODO Daten Liefern
            for (Order order : orders) {
                if(!order.getUserid().equals(token.getUser().getId())){
                    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/logout");
                }
                Statistics st = new Statistics(order.getProperties(), order.getId());
                statistics.add(st);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        List<Statistics> statistics_back = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = statistics.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            statistics_back.add(statistics.get(i));
        }
        return new ModelAndView("my_orders")
                .addObject("statistics", statistics_back);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically OAuth2 is to authorize external application or API in your application. Say if you are using Google Docs in your application, then you may have to authorize your client to access the Docs provided by Google by redirecting the client to Google and authenticate to google and authorized to access Docs from your application. Once Authorized you will get an authorization code with which whenever the client wants to access Docs the same code will be used for him to access.

If you want a perfect authentication to your application, then I suggest you to collect username and password from your client and store it in a database with encryption and decryption provided by spring security.

In my stand, OAuth will not be a perfect authentication platform.